# Finding the Probability Density Function of a random variable

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables whose marginal PDF's are uniform on $[0,5],$ and $Z=X+Y$. I want to find the Probability Density Function.

To start I assume I need to find the cumulative density function. I tried to follow a similar problem [here](https://www.quora.com/Let-X-and-Y-be-two-independent-random-variables-whose-marginal-pdfs-are-fX-x-1-0%E2%89%A4-x-%E2%89%A41-and-fY-y-1-0%E2%89%A4-y-%E2%89%A41-What-is-the-pdf-of-X-+-Y), but was unable to adapt it to my own problem.

Comment: The pdf for $Z$ is the convolution of your two pdfs. If you take the convolution of two constants ($=1/5$) you should end up with a triangle-shaped pdf.

Comment: How do I take a convolution in this context?

Comment: What do you know and not know about the definition of convolution.  In your case it is very straightforward.

Comment: All I know is that I need to take $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\,dx.$, but beyond that it is not straightforward for me.

Comment: Observe that $f_X=1/5$ in $[0,5]$ and zero elsewhere. Same for $Y$. If you fix some $z$, your integral only extends to those $x$ such that $x\in[0,5]$ and $z-x\in[0,5]$. Look at all possible cases for the intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not learned about convolution products, just find the CDF first.
$$
P(X+Y\leq t)=\int_0^{t-u}\frac{1}{5}(\int_0^{u} \frac{1}{5}du)dx
$$
for $0\leq t \leq 5$.
It is actually better to draw the square $[0,5]^2$ and evaluate the area geometrically.

The CDF should be
$$
\frac{1}{50}t^2, (0\leq t\leq 5)\\
1-\frac{1}{50}(10-t)^2, (5\leq t\leq 10)\\
0, (\text{otherwise})
$$

If you differentiate this you get the PDF
$$
\frac{1}{25}t, (0\leq t\leq 5)\\
\frac{1}{25}(10-t), (5\leq t\leq 10)\\
0, (\text{otherwise})
$$
which is a "triangle" if you plot it.

Comment: Thank you! One question, should there be a minus sign in front of $\frac{1}{25}(10-5)$?

Comment: No. PDF cannot be negative. Just be careful with differentiation.

Comment: Fascinating, okay, I will keep that in mind.